# Do you perform any validation on the OpenID URI?

Tags: validation, openid, dotnetopenauth

When you are logging in a user using OpenID, do you perform any validation on the OpenID URI (or identifier)? Or do you just let the library handle it (like [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/)).

Comment: Hey Pablo, if you like my answer, can you check it off as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth handles all validation.  Web sites that add validation are likely to needlessly break some OpenIDs (for example, when XRI support was added, those don't look like URLs, and a web site that tried to make it look like a URL would break XRIs).